# Return rows that have every kind of instances that appear in a table for a given attribute

Tags: sql

E.g, given the schema:

```
account(id, type, cname)
```

I want to return the `cname`s of customers with every `type` of account that appears in `account`.

The following query will do:

```
SELECT cname, type
FROM account AS cust_account 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT type 
    FROM account 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT type 
    FROM account 
    WHERE account.cname = cust_account.cname
);
```

However, I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind it. In particular, I don't see what's going on with the `EXCEPT` statement. Can anybody clarify this? Thank you.

Comment: I think I have understand the logic, but I don't find sense in that query. It's like a recursive query, but the `NOT EXISTS` kill the sense for me. You said that the query works.. Can you give an example of your data and the result for that query for that data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `WHERE NOT EXIST` clause processes each record, it runs the following steps for the customer in that record. If it sees an empty list from step #3 it will include the customer in the query results  (`NOT EXISTS`) .

1. Make a list of all the possible account types.
2. Make list of all accounts types that THIS customer has.
3. Subtract the list in step #2 *from* the list in step #1. This will create a list of any account types that THIS customer does NOT have. This will be empty for customers that have all accounts.

To be clear, since the `WHERE NOT EXIST` clause contains a correlated-sub query, steps 1-3 (which are performed by the sub query) are run one time for EACH row in the account table. For example, if the accounts table contains 100,000, the sub query will be run 100,000 times.

Comment: I understand the subquery, but I don't understand that the complete query could return any row, because the subquery reads from `cust_account` and there is a recursion that I'm not understanding how  is possible that the complete query could return something. I think always returns 0 rows.

Comment: @Carexcer: Try extracting your subquery and running it for just one customer at a time to see what it does. For a customer that has all the types, it will not return anything. For a customer that only has a some accounts, it will return the accounts the customer does NOT have. I also added to my answer.

Comment: @poke: Thank you so much, that was a crystal clear explanation and it allowed me to see how the aliased table is needed to compare _every_ row from `account.cname` against _just one_ row from `cust_account.cname` at time!
Just out of curiosity, is there a better way to achieve the same result? Does it actually make sense as a query or is it just a clever way to show how `NOT EXISTS` works?

Comment: @laurids: No problem. There are much more efficient ways to do this, but that's a separate question :-).